# Frequency Scaling and current draw

Tags: power, current, frequency, raspberry-pi

I am trying to power a RPi of 4 AA's, and my mobile power device can only output limited current (500mA), but I can underpower my RPi by frequency scaling. Is frequency scaling and current draw a linear relationship?

Answer (score 4):

Generally no. There will be some component of current draw that is linear, which represents the switching losses of the CMOS logic. But there also be various static (constant) loads as well, including such things as CMOS leakage current, the operating current for other components operating at a constant frequency, pullup resistors, etc.

Comment: So power is proportional to f, with some other current leakage added on?

Comment: There is probably a large number of factors, one being proportional to frequency, one being leakage current. Only way to find out is to do couple measurements averaged with various frequencies and then plot it in a graph.